# Adding two header views in one UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView called "myTable" which is in a ViewController. I have a custom header view called "theHeaderView" which contains some text and an image in it. So far so good.

When I tried to add a UISearchBar to the same table, it is not visible: My guess is that the search box is covered by my "theHeaderView" which is already added before.

Now the big question of mine is:
Is it possible to add both views "the search box" and "theHeaderView" in the myTable.tableHeaderView?

P.S. I have only one section in myTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not, because both search and headerview are toolbars. Try to put searchbar into headerview.

Comment: Yeah, I already did that and it is working fine. But I thought there is another workaround :-).
Many Thanks